# How to migrate attachments stored on a fileshare, referenced in MS Access, to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access

I have an MS Access database that we're converting to a SQL Server backend. This database has an `Attachments` table with a few simple columns:

```
PK, FK to MainTable.RecordID, Description, filename
```

Attachments are stored in a fileshare. VBA code uses a hardcoded filepath and `ShellExecute` to save attachments to a directory, under a `RecordID` subfolder.

We're moving to store attachments in SQL Server using filestream.

I need to move these attachments from fileshare, to SQL Server, while maintaining `RecordID` integrity. SQL Server tables and columns are already set up.

These attachments vary in extensions (.msg, .doc, .xlsx, .pdf)

I've been looking into "OPENROWSET" but every example I've seen uses only one file.

I've been looking into SSMA but can't find what I'm looking for.

Any references/reference articles or code resources I can use/repurpose would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `I need to move these attachments from fileshare, to SQL Server` why? Why not keep using a path and fileshare? This isn't a trivial operation, it *does* affect the database and requires careful design. Right now any application can edit those files by using the path. Web sites can use streaming to return the files without loading them in memory. If you just insert the contents into the database, no application will be able to edit them.

Comment: The `why` matters. You can use [FILESTREAM storage or FileTables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/binary-large-object-blob-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16) to store file data in table with the actual bytes getting stored in the file system. You maintain stream access and with FileTables, you can use UNC-style paths to access those files

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - simply answered, because I'm being told to. Logically, there's no reason to break what currently works. But, folks above me want it that way.

Comment: @SadlyFullStack - VBA code can reach the files AND SQL Server tables now.

Comment: Are you asking how to run a stored procedure in SQL Server to find all the files in a directory and convert/store them into an SQL table? I have some code that uses `master.sys.xp_dirtree` to read in all files in a directory. If you know how to convert one file into a filestream using OPENROWSET, then you can iterate over all the files returned by `xp_dirtree`. Would that help?

Comment: `because I'm being told to` is never an answer. You can't decide on a storage strategy without actually knowing the `why`, and the requirements. Do you need editing or not for example? That's a pretty big concern. `varbinary(max)` is seldom a good idea except for small files. Once you know that answer you could write ~ 5 lines in any script or language to iterate over all files in a folder structure and insert them into the database. Crawling a folder in Python, PowerShell, C# is a one-liner, eg `Directory.EnumerateFiles(pathToFolder,"*.png",SearchOption.AllDirectories)`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - the answer is the answer. Right now I'm tasked with moving these files from the directory to SQL Server table - while maintaining referential integrity. That's all I'm concerned with. Why, who, where, what, how, is above my ladder rung.

Comment: @JuniperSquared the difference between senior and junior is that they do ask why, so they can pick the correct solution. You *decided* to store the files inside the database data files without the possibility of editing. This will cause buffering and caching issues. Why did *you* decide that, when you could still have referential integrity but save the files outside the DB? The queries wouldn't change. The field would still be `varbinary(max)`. Referential integrity would still be enforced

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - and the difference between employed and unemployed is insubordination. You're making a significant amount of inferences and assumptions that are neither factual nor what I asked for. Thanks for the tips, but I'm all set with what I came for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to write an SQL stored procedure that will find all files in a given file path, iterate over those files, and insert the file into a table.

This article will help in general: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5432/stored-procedure-to-import-files-into-a-sql-server-filestream-enabled-table/

This article is about xp_dirtree: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/how-to-use-xp_dirtree-to-list-all-files-in-a-folder

Here's sample code to read the file system from SQL. THIS IS UNTESTED CODE, you'll need to modify to your needs but it gives you some idea of how to do the loops and read in files.

```
--You will need xm_cmdshell enabled on SQL server if not already.
USE master
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced option',1
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell',1
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
GO

--Create a variable to hold the pickup folder.
DECLARE @PickupDirectory nvarchar(512) = '\\folder_containing_files_or_folders\';

--Create a temp table to hold the files found in the pickup directory.
PRINT 'Parsing directory to identify most recent file.';
DECLARE @DirTree TABLE (
    id int IDENTITY(1,1)
    , subdirectory nvarchar(512)
    , depth int
    , isfile bit
);

--Enumerate the pickup directory.
INSERT @DirTree
EXEC master.sys.xp_dirtree @PickupDirectory,1,1 --Second variable is depth.

--Create variables to loop through folders and files.
DECLARE @folderCount int;
DECLARE @folderName nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @folderPath nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @i int = 0;

DECLARE @fileCount int;
DECLARE @fileName NVARCHAR(max);
DECLARE @filePath varchar(max);
DECLARE @j int = 0;


DECLARE @RecordID nvarchar(50);
DECLARE @SQLText NVARCHAR(max);
 
SET @folderCount = (SELECT Count(*) FROM @DirTree WHERE isfile = 0);
 
WHILE ( @i < @folderCount )
BEGIN
    --Get the next folder to process.
    SET @folderName = (
        SELECT TOP 1 subdirectory 
        FROM @DirTree as dt
            LEFT OUTER JOIN @processedFolders as pf
                on pf.folder_name = dt.subdirectory
        WHERE isfile = 0 
            AND pf.folder_name IS NULL
    );

    --Get the recordID from folder name.
    SET @recordID = @folderName; --Edit this to get the RecordID from your folder structure.

    --Concat root path and new folder to get files from.
    SET @folderPath = @PickupDirectory + @folderName + '\';

    --Enumerate the this subdirectory to process files from.
    INSERT @filesToProcess
    EXEC master.sys.xp_dirtree @folderPath,1,1

    --Get count of files to loop through.
    SET @fileCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @filesToProcess WHERE isfile = 1);

    WHILE (@j < @fileCount)
    BEGIN
        --Get next filename.
        SET @fileName = (SELECT TOP 1 subdirectory FROM @filesToProcess WHERE isfile = 1);

        --Concat the whole file path.
        SET @filePath = @folderPath + @fileName;
 
        SET @SQLText = '
            INSERT INTO [table_name](RecordID,[filename],[filestreamCol])   
            SELECT 
                ''' + @RecordID + '''
                , ''' + @fileName + '''
                , BulkColumn 
            FROM OPENROWSET(Bulk ''' + @filePath + ''', Single_Blob) as tb'
 
        EXEC Sp_executesql @SQLText

        DELETE FROM @filesToProcess
        WHERE subdirectory = @fileName;

        SET @j = @j + 1;
    END

    INSERT INTO @processedFolders (folder_name)
    SELECT @folderName;

    PRINT 'Folder complete: ' + @folderName;

    SET @i = @i + 1
END
```

I think you want to parse just a root directory with the xp_dirtree command above. That will display all the subdirectories which should contain the "RecordID". Read the RecordID into a variable,  then parse each of those subdirectories to get the actual files. If you want more detailed code, you'll have to show some examples of the directory structure and the destination table.

Comment: This is more than enough to get me in the direction that I need to go. If I need something more specific - after working through this a bit - I'll pop a separate question.

Thanks!

Comment: Updated with more complete loop. It's untested code but should be a fairly close example to get you closer to your goal. The #Final_Document table is from one of the links I posted. From my code, it would probably be best to convert the @filesToProcess into a temp table #filesToProcess, and then complete that dynamic SQL piece for the actual OPENROWSET operation. Sorry it's not complete, I just don't have the time to test in my environment ATM.

Comment: I couldn't let that dynamic sql go... had to clean it up to make it more readable. I don't want to be judged on copy-and-pasted code with sloppy formatting.

Comment: This is a bad idea and fragile code, and not just because of the potential for SQL injection. This is weakening security to do what *any* scripting language or C# would do far better. Almost all of this code can be replaced with a couple of Python, Powershell or C# lines that go through a folder and pick files. What's left is the 2-3 lines that would INSERT that file's contents into the database. And that doesn't even touch whether `varbinary(max)` makes sense.

Comment: If run in a controlled environment for a specific purpose, it fits the need. The OP is doing a conversion from Access to SQL Server. After the project is complete, they can turn off xp_cmdshell and delete the store procedure. No need to get another programming language involved for an afternoon project. Thank you for pointing out the potential for SQL injection.