# Import Multiple JSON Files to SQL Server from a Folder

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, powershell-3.0

I have a folder on the SQL server called C:\JSON this folder will be continually populated with JSON files that need to be ingested into a SQL table which exists.  I have a working TSQL statement that will populate with a specific file being named.

What I'm wanting is to have a SQL variable to loop thru the files and ingest the files into the table

The SQL statement which works to ingest a single specific file is:

```
Declare @JSON varchar(max)
SELECT @JSON=BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'c:\json\test.JSON', SINGLE_CLOB) import
INSERT INTO __JSONTable
SELECT * 
FROM OPENJSON (@JSON)
WITH 
(
    [id] nvarchar(20), 
    [to] nvarchar(20), 
    [from] nvarchar(20), 
    [call_type] nvarchar(20), 
    [start_time] nvarchar(100), 
    [duration] nvarchar(10), 
    [external-call-id] nvarchar(100),
    [external-tracking-ids] nvarchar(100),
    [original-filename] nvarchar(100),
    [recorder-call-id] nvarchar(100),
    [recorder-identifier] nvarchar(100),
    [recording-platform] nvarchar(100)
)
```

What I need is to set a variable on the 'c:\json\test.json' value to look to the next .json file in the folder and ingest it into the table.  I wish to script this as a stored procedure or a powershell script.

Comment: What about that are you stuck on? Or are you asking us to do it all for you?

Comment: This is all wrong. What you need is to have an external process that enumerates the files and inserts their content into your staging table. SQL Server shouldn't be inspecting the file system looking for new files and managing imports itself - what will happen if/when you migrate your DEV/UAT/PRD databases to Azure SQL, SQL Server for Linux and/or Docker containers and there isn't even a C: drive any more, let alone a C:\json folder?

Comment: I posted a code sample for iterating through a file folder in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74143300/2452207). @AlwaysLearning is right in a way but I do find it useful to do one off imports and migrations completely within SQL server. Creating a console application is sometimes overkill in my mind. If this is a reoccurring task, then yes, develop that application as it will be a more portable/extensible solution.